# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu not working over 3G/Cellular Network

Tags: iphone, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, 3g

My Bootstrap Menu works absolutely fine on desktop systems, and even on iPhone/iPad when connected via Wireless. However, as soon as I test over a 3G/Cellular connection (ie. Disable WiFi), the dropdown menu does NOT appear.

What's even stranger is that the examples on the Bootstrap website all work fine over 3G, so I copied and pasted there exact code into my site to test and it doesn't work!

Here's the default dropdown code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </div>
```

Again, this all works fine over WiFi, but the drowndown menu does not appear when on 3G, even though the bootstrap example works fine...

UPDATE: This issue was fixed simply by updating the bootstrap.js (must have got changed/corrupted at some point?) BUT the latest 2.1.0 introduced a bug where dropdown menu items cannot be selected. Reported here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4756

Comment: Does it work on the [Twitter Bootstrap Page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)?

Comment: After some more testing, I updated the bootstrap.js file with the latest version, and now the drodown menu DOES appear when the button is pressed (on Wifi and on 3G), however, the menu items are NOT clickable! As soon as you click on the dropdown, it dissapears. This is also repeatable on the actual bootstrap page you linked to (Try any of the dropdown buttons on iPhone)

Comment: That is not a iPhone issue.  It is actually a bug ([Issue #4497](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4497) that was introduced with 2.1. I posted a workaround in the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12124808/570918.

Comment: @merv, I really appreciate your help, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue for me. Just to be 100% clear, my issue is that I cannot click any of the items of a button dropdown menu (on iPhone). When I click on an item it doesn't even register the "highlight" state of the menu item, the dropdown just closes. It's almost as if the click is going through the menu as anything beneath it gets clicked instead.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, then I'd recommend posting a different question, and mention that you already tried the fix to [Issue #4497](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4497) and it didn't make a difference. You might also want to file your own issue on the Bootstrap repo.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4756