# How to get mouse click event in jquery over facebook like plugin?

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-selectors, facebook-like

Here I am calling facebook like plugin in iFrame after click in that iframe I want to perform some script in my DOM content.

Here code for facebook like plugin for iframe

```
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? 
       href=http://yoururl.com/&amp;
       layout=button_count&amp;
       show_faces=false&amp;
       width=50&amp;
       action=like&amp;
       colorscheme=light&amp;
       height=21" 
       scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
       style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px;  
              height:21px;" 
       allowTransparency="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery).

Summary: Binding click events for iframes can be done, but not cross-site.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the fbml version of the Facebook like button.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

And you can use the following code to do what you want:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // perform some script in your DOM content 
});
```