# How to add onclick event to Gauge of Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, jquery-events

I need to handle the `onclick` event over a Gauge. I don't have found an example for register events over Gauges on the Google Chart documentation.

I have tried the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","gauge"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'LABEL');
                data.addColumn('number', 'TOTAL');
                data.addRows(1);
                data.setValue(0, 0, 'Speed');
                data.setValue(0, 1, 240);
                var gaugeOptions = {min: 0, max: 280, yellowFrom: 200, yellowTo: 250, title: 'Company Performance', redFrom: 250, redTo: 280, minorTicks: 5};
                var gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
                gauge.draw(data, gaugeOptions);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(gauge, 'select', function() {
                    alert("Here");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gauge_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I have tried to add onclick event with JQuery to div "gauge_div" but it only works if I make click on the border of div, not over the gauge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauge has no events that it triggers.  The chart is rendered in an iframe, which also does not have a click event in the local dom, but rather in the window.document.body of the iframe.  A solution I used was to create an empty div relatively positioned on top of the gauge and register the click event on that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","gauge"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'LABEL');
                data.addColumn('number', 'TOTAL');
                data.addRows(1);
                data.setValue(0, 0, 'Speed');
                data.setValue(0, 1, 240);
                var gaugeOptions = {min: 0, max: 280, yellowFrom: 200, yellowTo: 250, title: 'Company Performance', redFrom: 250, redTo: 280, minorTicks: 5};
                var gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
                gauge.draw(data, gaugeOptions);
                google.visualization.events.addListener(gauge, 'select', function() {
                    alert("Here");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="position:relative;">
        <div id="gauge_div"></div>
        <div id="gauge_div_clickable" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:- 120px;width:120px;height:120px;" onclick="alert('here');">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this works if you have just one Gauge, but when you have many gauges rendered I want to get the onclick event and identify the originator.

Comment: In that case you may want to look into how to capture the click event from an iframe.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery one can use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) something like this...

```
$( "#gauge_div td:nth-child(2)" ).click(function() {
    var tData = data.getValue(1,0);
    alert( "Handler for .click() called."+ tDate);
});
```

Assuming your gauge data is held in a variable called "data" you would call the second child and the correct data row would be row "1", as it will start with 0.

ie 0=1, 1=2, 2=3, 3=4, ...

Answer (score 0):

To get clickable gauge, add this javascript:

```
$('#gauge_div').find('iframe')).each(function(elt, idx) {
   $(elt).contents().find('body').click(function (event) {
      // gauge.getSelection() does not exists so we emulate its result:
      var selection = [{'row': idx}];
      common_onclick_callback(selection);
   });
});
```

Which features:

- distinct gauge `onclick` (works with several gauges, and identifies them)
- sample of a quick `gauge.getSelection()` result emulation, which could be helpfull if you want to re-use an `onclick` callback that you would have already written for other google charts type.

This works because:

- each `iframe` is looked to hook the event in their `body` (otherwise `onclick` event isn't triggered)
- each `onclick` callback gets an appropriate index `idx` related to their position in the HTML.

This sample uses:

- jquery which is mapped to `$`, and provide selector and `find`, `contents` methods
- underscore which is mapped to `_`, and provide the `each` facility

But both of these are optional but convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I started with CrandellWS's answer, but ended up with the following, which is even simpler:

```
$('#gauge_div td').click(function() {
   alert(data.getValue(this.cellIndex,0));
});
```