# Add a click event to iframe in jquery

Tags: jquery

My DOM has iframe with `id=""` and `name =""`.

The iframe has a form inside, inside the form is a table and I need to fire a click event on the table data. The table data(td) has a link. When the link is clicked a function needs to fire off.

How do I get this working using jQuery?

Comment: Maybe this one will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Can you post the html you're using? Also blank id and name attributes don't seem correct -- or at least not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like this:

```
$("#iframeID").contents().find("td.data").children("a").on("click", function() {
    // do something
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The id="" is that case how to use #iframeID also what is td.data. can you explain because the above did not seem to work.