# Check mouse click on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I check with javascript when mouse click on iframe, because iframe don't support "on" events?

That is my iframe:

And I use this jquery code:

$('#ifr31').bind('click', function(event) { alert(1) });

But when I click on iframe don't alert nothing?

Comment: are you working with iframe of same domain

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609808/561545

> There's no 'onclick' event for an iframe, but you can try to catch the
>   click even of the document in the iframe:
>
> document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick
>   =  function() {   alert("iframe clicked"); }
>
> EDIT Though this doesn't solve your cross site problem, FYI jQuery has
>   been updated to play well with iFrames:
>
> $('#iframe_id').bind('click', function(event) { });

Answer (score 0):

if same origin you can use  `$('#ifame').bind('click', function(event) { });`

Answer (score 0):

Only works on iframes on the same domain:

```
$('body', $('select-your-iframe-here').contents()).click(function(event) {
  console.log('Clicked! ' + event.pageX + ' - ' + event.pageY);
});
```