# Add click event to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to add a click event to an `iframe`. I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery) and got this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#left').bind('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});

<iframe src="left.html" id="left">
</iframe>
```

But unfortunately nothing happens.
When I test it with another element (e.g. a button), it works:

```
<input type="button" id="left" value="test">
```

Comment: Why don't you just add it to left.html?

Comment: I have several iframe on my page. I want that context menu to be expandable over them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could attach the click to the iframe content:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});
```

Note: this will only work if both pages are in the same domain.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/

Comment: Oh, i see. It only works when i click the text, but not somewhere else on the page.

Comment: It works when you click anywhere within the iframe body. Here is another example where the click is attached to the window: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/1/

Comment: The code in your Life demo worked for me: `$($("iframe")[0].contentWindow).on('contextmenu', function(e) { alert('test'); });`

Comment: It is also possible, to add the click-event on a specific DIV within this iframe? My iframe is devided into 2 divs and only on of them should be clickable.

Comment: Sure :-) $(this).contents().find("#idOfTheClickableDiv"). contents() is the iframe document, from there you can reach whatever you want within the iframe... provided that you don't break the same origin policy.

Comment: @Christophe: can u take a look at the basic plnkr created frm ur example. Its not working. :( https://plnkr.co/edit/KDUpwWd76ESrqHXIvrpN?p=preview

Comment: @SaurabhMistry the live demo is not working for you?

Comment: AKA this is NOT an option if you're doing a youtube.com iFrame and trying to know when that youtube video inside the iFrame clicked... since youtube.com != your domain... :( ... For others trying to do Google Analytics against embedded youtube videos on your page.

Answer (score 22):

Two solutions:

1. Using `:after` on a `.iframeWrapper` element
2. Using `pointer-events:none;` one the iframe

### 1. Using `:after`

use a transparent overlay `::after` pseudo element with **higher z-index** on the iframe's wrapper DIV element. Such will help the wrapper to register the click:

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready
  
   $('.iframeWrapper').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('test');
   });
  
});
```

```css
.iframeWrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.iframeWrapper::after{ /* I have higher Z-index so I can catch the click! Yey */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.iframeWrapper iframe{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="iframeWrapper">
  <iframe src="http://www.reuters.tv/" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

### 2. Using `pointer-events:none;`

Clicks are not handleable from outside the iframe **from an external resource** (if the iframe is not in your domain).
You can only create that function inside your *'called into iframe'* page, not from within the *iframe-hosting* page.

**How to do it**:

- You can **wrap** your `iframe` into a div
- make the click "go through" your `iframe` using CSS `pointer-events:none;`
- target clicks with `jQuery` on your wrapping `DIV` (the `iframe` parent element)

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready
  
   $('.iframeWrapper').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('test');
   });
  
});
```

```css
.iframeWrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.iframeWrapper iframe{
  vertical-align:top;
  pointer-events: none; /* let any clicks go trough me */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="iframeWrapper">
  <iframe src="http://www.reuters.tv/" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**NOTA BENE:**

- No clicks will be registered by the iframe element, so a use-case would be i.e: if by clicking the iframe you want to enlarge it full screen.... Etc...

Comment: @Christophe doh, forgot to mention that IE cannot even handle `position` properly... :) (should we even note that) ;) kidding, thanks

Comment: how can you "release" that click back to the iframe ?

Comment: @RickyLevi I think there's no way to do so. If there was one it would be a security / privacy issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work but only after uploading it to a host. I imagine localhost would work fine too.

**outer**

```
<html>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
            $(myFrame.contentWindow.document).find("div").on("click", function () { alert("clicked"); });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myFrame" src="inner.htm"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**inner**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                padding:2px;
                border:1px solid black;
                display:inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Click Me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: will be blocked on CORS

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Javascript

Not my solution but only this works well.

```
let myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#left').click(function(event) { alert('test'); });
});

<iframe src="left.html" id="left">Your Browser Does Not Support iframes</iframe>
```

The script would have to be ran entirely from the iframe. I would recommend a different method of calling content, such as php.

iframes aren't really worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that, the click event does not bind to the DOM of the iframe and bind() is deprecated, use `.on()` to bind the event. Try with the following codes and you will find the borders of the iframe clickable getting that alert.

```
$('#left').on('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
```

[Demo of that Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/HtUvG/)

> #### So how to get it done?

How you should do is, create a function on iframe page, and call that function from that iframe page.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was just wondering, why it appears to work in the example mentioned above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery).

Comment: @RickyLevi, Do you have an example JsFiddle to show?

Comment: I just load the link in the comment, and click on the IFRAME, according to that code - an alert should popup ( or maybe I misunderstood the demo ) ... the alert never pops.