# How to detect click event in iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is my iframe:

```
#htmlDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
    height: 650px;
    width: 1130px;
}

#htmlFrame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 630px;
    width: 1110px;
}

<div id="htmlDiv">
    <iframe id="htmlFrame"></iframe>
</div>

$('#htmlFrame').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

But when I click inside the iframe, it doesn't show "clicked".
How do I detect click inside iframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add click event to a iframe with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work to me.

Comment: Take a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript#answer-23231136

Comment: So try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot detect a click event on an `iframe`. What can be done is you can place a `overlapping layer` on top of your `iframe` and capture the click event of the overlapping div. See below snippet:

```js
$("#overlap").on("click",function(){
  alert("click");
  $("#overlap").css("z-index",-1);

});
$("#htmlFrame").on("mouseleave",function(){
  $("#overlap").css("z-index",1);
});
```

```css
#htmlDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    width: 113px;
}

#htmlFrame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 63px;
    width: 110px;
}

#overlap{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:trasparent;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 110px;
  height:63px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmlDiv">
    <iframe id="htmlFrame"></iframe>
  <div id="overlap">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then the click doesn't propagate to the iframe, does it?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is working fine, try to click it to the border of the `iframe` and the alert will show. I tried to create a solution for you by adding an overlay to the `iframe`

You can see the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vp268eyx/1/)

```
<div id="htmlDiv">
    <iframe id="htmlFrame"></iframe>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <iframe src="..."></iframe>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;eventual mouse cursor style" onclick="eventual alternative action"></div>
</div>
```