# Is it possible to change iFrame style (not on the same domain) after the first click

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a page on which I have an iframe (containing a page from another domain) and it is set to show a certain part of the page. However, I want to make it so that after the first click the iFrame moves to show a lower part of the source page. Is this possible?

With regards,

SJA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overall solution is formed of following steps:

1. You should detect the click on iframe
2. then reload the second target which you need to be scrolled to in the iframe's inner page.(e.g. : [iframePageURL]/index.html#secondTarget)

Now lets dive into detailed explanation:

**item 1 in detail:**
in order to detect click on an iframe you need to put a transparent overlaying layer on it : [Consult the answer here which has offered the solution in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403734/how-to-detect-click-event-in-iframe-using-jquery#answer-37403915). You just need a flag to unset it after the first click.

**Item 2 in detail:** Now that you've got user's click on the iframe, change the iframe's `src` to the desired target, using sth like this:

```
document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am looking into the first item and was wondering for the second item if I can use this then to not change the iframe source, but the iframe style. For example if I can capture the click,I would like to change the iframe width from 200 to 300 or whatever. I am guessing this is possible, but just to be sure.

Comment: Sure you can, using sth like this: `document.getElementById("myFrame").width = "400";`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, have been quite sick unfortunately. Thanks again for the help, it worked applying it!

Comment: You're welcome @SweatyJoeAllen, God bless. glad to hear it worked.