# onclick and pointer-events:none

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

So i have this image that styled with Pointer-events:none, with a iframe beneath it. I've lined the iframe up with my own play button (the img with the Pointer-events:none) so when you click it a song is played. What i want to do is having the play icon change to a Pause icon. The problem is when the iframe (spotify) doesn't work with onclick so i cant call a toggle function. Is it posible to have another div or something like it between the image and the that also have pointer-events:none but can call a javascript function?

Comment: Looks like it might be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403915/4573410

Comment: The problem is that you can't transfer a click through a div (which is capturing the click event) down into the iframe.

Comment: I know that onclick on a div is not the way to go but with jQuery there could be a chance. The problem with that link is that they dont use pointer-events:none. Without it i dont think i can press the button to start the iframe :/!