# How to bind click event to iframe/embed in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

Edit: found the solution [How to detect click event in iframe using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403734/how-to-detect-click-event-in-iframe-using-jquery)

I want to count have many people watch my youtube video from my site. How can I do that?
I've tried to bind click, mouseup & mousedown in Iframe. But it doesn't work.
I also cannot bind anything in embed tag.
My call function send data to my google analytic

It seems I don't have control inside the iframe. If I click on the border of my Ifram and it work fine.

Thanks

```
<iframe class="border-frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cQqRX0GC_6I?list=RDcQqRX0GC_6I" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen (mousedown)="logit()"></iframe>

<embed class="border-frame" src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/cQqRX0GC_6I?list=RDcQqRX0GC_6I">
```

Comment: `mousedown` is a jquery event. you can use `(click)` event

Comment: its called analytics: https://www.youtube.com/googleanalytics

Comment: I want to know the number access from my site, not all views. I have tried (click) and it doesn't work either.