# Catch keydown events iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe which I include on my page.

```
<iframe  scrolling="no" src="https://xx.com/" ></iframe>
```

xx.com doesn't allow cross-origin ( I don't remember how exactly is this parameter called, but I can't really access contents of iframe)

So what are my options to capture a keydown event which happens within this iframe? I tried

```
`$('iframe').keydown(function(e){console.log(1)});`
```

But didn't work(

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Add click event to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe).

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjyr3nhd/)

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('keydown', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});
$('iframe').attr("src","JavaScript:'iframe content'");
```