# How to attach click event on iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I want to make an iframe clickable so that I can associate an `ng-click` or a javascript event listener to it.

Actually, I want to call some function once it's clicked

## Update1:

As per the comment [I tried this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe) & created the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KDUpwWd76ESrqHXIvrpN?p=preview) but it's not working

Comment: You can't directly. All events related to iframe occur inside the iframe window and are not propagated to the parent page window

Comment: @charlietfl: I tried to create an overlay effect using a div and attach click event to it. It works on Chrome but on IE div stays behind the iframe. So can you provide me a good approach plz :(

Comment: Does the `iframe` `src` have same domain as parent `window`?

Comment: see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @selvarajmas, please check the update