# How to capture click on iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to capture click on iframe using javascript.

I'm using this code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pin').contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  alert("iframe clicked");
}
```

But it is not able to capture any click of the iframe. I can only use javascript.
I'm getting this error
"SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin"

Comment: Is the iframe coming from the same host / domain?

Comment: See if this helps : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` which doesn't have a `contentWindow` property. Either try `document.getElementsByClassName('pin')[0]` or walk on the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var i = 0; 
//i represents the exact node since obtaining node by class name gives array of nodes.
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('pin')[i].contentWindow;
```

or

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow;

iframe.document.body.onmousedown = 
function() {
  alert("iframe clicked");
}
```