# open a new windows when clicking a adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to open the current page in a new window when the user click on the Adsense ADS

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var link= $(location).attr('href');
    $('.pub').click(function(){
      window.open(link);
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="pub">
  here the ADS Code 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `location.href`, not `$(location).attr('href')`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var link = location.href;
  $('.pub').click(function(){
    window.open(link);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i try ths but always the same result

Comment: @RamiRiahi are you sure that a) code is executed b) new window is not blocked

Comment: yes because the code run perfectly with the other <div> but when i click on the ADS block its didn't work

Comment: I guess Adsense blocks event propagation to stop you from doing what you intend to do :) Adsense shows ads in iframes, consider looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1609741