# Open confirmation modal pop up from button click inside chase paymentech Irfame

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, iframe, asp.net-ajax

We have an Asp.net mvc website with credit card processing view. The view basically has a Chase Orbitel paymentech Iframe. We want to display confirmation modal pop up before user click the button in the Iframe to submit the payment. Our problem is that as soon as we click the submit button inside the chase Iframe , we don't know how to display the modal using jquery/JavaScript. We are still new with callbacks. Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Michael: Thanks for your comment. It looks like we are sort of out of luck with 3rd party IFrame in this case.

Comment: Yes I never found any solution for accessing content of third party in iframe.