# How to click element on iframe? Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good afternoon. On the site (for example) nnmclub.to
have some ad units in the iframe.
How to implement a click on them?

I clicked on the part of the href links (links are kind of like http: //site.xyz) click on .xyz. But it opens the same source site and not link that was clicked on. That is, clicks but returned nnmclub.to.

Options are tried

1. ```
   <script>
       window.onload = function() {
         document.querySelector('a[href*=".xyz"]').click(); 
       }
   </script>
   ```

   2.

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
       var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
       for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
         var link = links[i].getAttribute('href');
         if (link.indexOf('.xyz') !== -1) {
           links[i].click();
           break;
         }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add click event to a iframe with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: did you implemented your function in the iframe html page ?

Comment: I need a click on one of link in this frame. frame in php code like this: <div id="some-id"></div> <script src="http://v.dlski.space/v/ad" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> </div>