# Use an input field in iframe as trigger for a Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Through this great forum I have managed to find a solution for expanding an iframe with a click through HTML and Jquery.

But it does not solve my problem completely. Where I am now I manage to expand the iframe using a text, but I want to use the input fields in the iframe as the trigger for the function.
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery) on how to use the iframe window itself as a trigger and it seems to use this plugin (iFrame Tracker): https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery

Sadly, this does not seem to work on mobile or other touch devices. Therefore, a click on the input field would be the optimal solution.

This is where I am now with a simple text that expands the height of the iframe when clicked:

HTML:

```
<iframe class="frame" iframe id="bestillframe" 
src="iframe source goes here" 
height="200px" width="200px"></iframe>   
<div id=kilden>
Click here to enlarge the iframe
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#kilden').click(function(){
    $('#bestillframe').animate({'height':'300'})  
    })
});
```

Fiddle with iframe link and mentioned input fields.
http://jsfiddle.net/b6qfJ/51/

Does anyone know how I can get this to work with a click on the input field?

Comment: If you have control over the content of the iframe, you can use `window.parent.function` to do so. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reread the question and realized that your objective is different than what I initially thought.

1. Just wrap the iframe in a block element and
2. make sure that the first thing the user clicks is the block element containing the iframe and not the iframe itself by making it unclickable with `pointer-events:none`.
3. Once the iframe has successfully enlarged, remove the click handler and enable the iframe to be clickable with `pointer-events:auto`.
4. Also, it helps to keep container and iframe together by using `position: relative` on the container and `position:absolute` on the iframe.

I'm well aware that you wanted the actual inputs to be `event.target` but besides the fact that it's impractical, the fact that at a height of 200px the user doesn't even see any inputs in the first place.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('section').on('click', expand);
});

function expand(e) {
  $('#iframe').animate({
    'height': '300'
  }).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  $('section').off('click', expand);
}
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px dashed red
}

#iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="iframe source goes here" height="200" width="200"></iframe>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the great help of @zer00ne I managed to work this out.
The only issue was that the above section seemed to scale along with the iframe automatic without proper formatting. This lead to an issue where all elements below the iframe would be overlapped and not moved accordingly downwards.
The solution was to give the section an ID and add another .animate function in the expand function so that they both would be triggered at the same time. Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works. And the solution would then be

**Solution**

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('section').on('click', expand);
});

function expand(e) {
  $('#ramme').animate({
    'height': '300'
  })
   $('#iframe').animate({
    'height': '300'
  }).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  $('section').off('click', expand);
}
```

HTML

```
<section id=ramme>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="iframe source goes here" height="200" 
width="900" scrolling="no";></iframe>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width:600px;
  padding: 0;
}

#iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**DEMO**
From fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/b6qfJ/92/

This is a great forum. Thanks!

Comment: Great I'm glad you found a solution. One thing to improve it is to replace `$('#ramme').animate({` with: `$(this).animate({`. It shouldn't change the behavior of the function itself, but just letting you know the alternative. It may not be significant here, but in the future you'll know the importance of `this`.

Comment: Thanks alot :-) I will try to change this and keep it mind for next time!