# Writing jQuery to change dimensions of dynamic iframe on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I am trying to a small script that will change the dimensions of an iframe when the iframe clicked. Here is the code for the iframe:

```js
$("#myKAframe").click(function () { 
    $('#myKAframe').css({ "height": "100%", "width": "100%" }); 
});
```

```html
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <iframe id="myKAframe" src="ka.html" title="KA"
        style=" padding: 0px; margin: 10px 20px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; overflow: visible; opacity: 1; border: 0px; z-index: 999998; transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); transition-property: opacity, top, bottom; right: 0px;">
 </iframe>
```

My issue is that, first of all, the code isn't working. And second, I don't know how to make the jquery such that when the iframe is clicked again, it goes back to the small dimensions. I'm pretty new to jQuery so any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to either put your script inside a `document.ready` callback, put it _after_ the markup it references, or use `event delegation`. All are well-trodden topics. Then, think though how you'd track state with a variable, cookie, local storage, or whatever. That part of your question is too broad.

Comment: `toggleClass()` is useful for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery), you can't add click listener to an iframe, but you can add listener to the body of the iframe (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609808/9977151))
and for creating the toggle system you can simply create a boolean that change is state every click

```js
var big = false;
$(function () {  
    $("#myKAframe").on("load",function(){


document.getElementById("myKAframe").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  if(big) $('#myKAframe').css({ "height": "auto", "width": "auto" }); 
  else $('#myKAframe').css({ "height": "100%", "width": "100%" }); 
  big = !big;
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<iframe id="myKAframe" src="https://www.example.com/" title="hello"
    style=" padding: 0px; margin: 10px 20px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; overflow: visible; opacity: 1; border: 0px; z-index: 999998; transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); transition-property: opacity, top, bottom; right: 0px;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense. But when I try implementing the code, I keep getting a "$ reference undefined", I don't think I know enough jquery to see what the problem is, but is there something I'm missing with regards to the placement of $ in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: did you add the jquery?

Comment: Yup. Actually It was just some files called out of scope. It works now! Thanks again!

Comment: @ConstantFuture so please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that `<iframe></iframe>` itself isn't a clickable element. **A click "on" an `iframe` is actually a click on content *inside* the `iframe`.**

It is possible to detect a click inside an `iframe`. Take a look at other [discussions of how to detect a click inside an `iframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+click+inside+iframe) here on SO.