# Capturing mousedown event on div with iframe child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to capture the mouse down event for the div containing the iframe. Is there any way to do it? It seems that the iframe is capturing the event and the mousedown event is not triggered for the div.

```js
jQuery(".test").on("mousedown", ()=> console.log("Test"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<a href="/" >Test</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: On which `test` class you have to perform mouse down event because you have two test class in your code

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej the used syntax automatically binds the click handler to _all_ elements with that class currently existing in the document.

Comment: What do you actually want to _achieve_ here? If you don't need to be able to interact with the iframe content, then you could simply put `pointer-events: none` on the iframe element ...

Comment: I'm doing some automation tasks, on the site there is a "Trust Pilot" link, embedded on an iframe, as I'm not able to get the event from the <a> tag inside the iframe, it would also work if I'm able to get it from the div where is embedded as it has the same size as the iframe. Also, it would be not possible to modify the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the only way you will be able to interact with iframe-content via javascript (and css aswell) is, if the scope of the domain is the same. Example-[Demo](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-detect-click-inside-iframe-using-javascript.php)

Any Cross-Domain interaction nowadays requires a [CORS-configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to allow for interaction between the different domains.

For that reason i would argue, that what you are trying to achieve is not really possible anymore (except if you are in control of both domains).

Comment: I'm not trying to interact with the iframe, I'm trying to interact with the parent div. But is seems that the iframe is capturing the event.

Comment: When the iframe content loads, everything within the iframe-container is not considered to be "your" website anymore. Therefore any javascript-interaction is not allowed, since that woud be an unauthenticated cross-domain-request.

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery) As mentioned in the comments of the top answer, your only way might be to use some sort of "hack" when you leave the realms of your own domain. Like putting and absolute positioned element above the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, not the best but it works for me

```js
jQuery(window).on('blur', function() {
  if (document.activeElement === document.querySelector('iframe')) {
    console.log('clicked on iframe')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <iframe id="testiframe" src="https://www.google.com/" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the `contents()` method, so:

```
jQuery(".test").contents().on("mousedown", ()=> console.log("Test"))
```

However, it can be a bit sketchy to intercept a click to someone else's page!! What are you doing with the click?

Comment: _"you can use the contents() method"_ - not if the iframe content is from a different origin, as is the case in the given example.

Comment: Oh, right. So then the op can't. Because it's too sketchy!